# Android MVP and Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, mosby

How to apply Firebase Analytics(for example) on MVP app architecture? (I use [Mosby](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby) to build MVP)

I want to track events of `"opening screen"`, `"do click action"`.

There is how I send `"opening screen"` event.

```
private const val ANALYTICS_SCREEN_NAME = "ask_password"
private const val ANALYTICS_ACTION_DONE = "done"
class AskPasswordPresenter : MyDiaryPresenter<AskPasswordView> {

    @Inject
    constructor(analytics: AnalyticsManager) : super(analytics) // AnalyticsManager is wrapper around Firebase Analytics API

    override fun initialize() { // this method called when new ViewState created
        super.initialize()
        analytics.doScreenOpened(ANALYTICS_SCREEN_NAME)
    }

    fun done(password: String) { // called when user click on 'Done' button
        ...
        analytics.doAction(ANALYTICS_SCREEN_NAME, ANALYTICS_ACTION_DONE)
    }
}
```

1. doAction(...) called as it must. Okay.
2. `initialize()` called even when user navigates back to the screen from backstack. I want it to send event ONLY when user navigates to screen in "front direction". It also looks like a bad solution as `initialize()` method introduced for initializing `Presenter` when `ViewState` was created at the first time, not for logging analytics events.

It sounds like I must share Fragment's lifecycle to Presenter. Not good.

What can you recommend? Must I create another entity, like AnalyticsPresenter for each Fragment? How do you handle this case?

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion Analytics belongs to the View layer and not Presenter layer.
So track it either directly in Fragment / Activity or (what I usually do) use one of the libraries like [lightcycle](https://github.com/soundcloud/lightcycle)
or [CompositeAndroid](https://github.com/passsy/CompositeAndroid) to kind of plug in a "Analytics component" to your Activity / Fragment. By doing so your Fragment / Activity doesn't contain the code for Analytics but is rather decoupled into its own class (single responsibility).

Comment: I disagree that `Analytics` belongs to the `View` layer. `View` is about showing info, not tracking it. But, wow! `CompositeAndroid` looks like a solution for my _"extends hell"_, thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score -1):

I think analytics belong to presenter, but as i answered on [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36123614/google-analytics-with-the-mvp-design-pattern?answertab=active#tab-top) question having analytics in View it's easier to jump on button/labels/... definitions and see where this button is located in UI and have better idea what to send for Category, Actio, Label and Value param of GAnalytics. I think i don't need to mention presenter mustn't have any android specific dependecies so you can't jump to button/labels/... definitions from presenter. Regards